# Behavior of inequalities expressed in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(10 > 9 < 8);
```

When I print this, I get the value `true`

Why is this so? Could someone please explain along with some documentation, if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
10 > 9 < 8
```

is

```
(10 > 9) <8
```

(because [comparison operators are left-associative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table))

which is

```
true < 8
```

where `true` is casted (using [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)) to a number, `1`

(details [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5))

Answer (score 6):

```
10 > 9 => is true
```

then true < 8 is true because true will be evaluated to 1